# In terraform tfvars file can we put value somewhere else and then simply we can just recall?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Can we put route table value somewhere else eg other tfvars file or varibles/local and then just in the tfvars file. we can call route table route_table =""

```
networks = {
  umms-security-vnet = {
    resource_group_name = "testrg" #required
    location            = "eastus"                      #required
    addressSpace = [
      "10.229.192.0/20" #required
    ]
    dnsServers = [
      "10.231.18.4",
      "146.189.24.10",
      "172.26.40.125"
    ]
    subnets = {
      GatewaySubnet = {
        addressPrefix = "10.229.192.0/24"
      }
      app-1-subnet = {
        addressPrefix                     = "10.229.198.0/24" #required
        route_table = {                                        #optional
          security-rt = {
            disableBgpRoutePropagation = false
            routes = [
              {
                name             = "default-udr"
                addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0"
                nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
                nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.100"
              },
              {
                name             = "network-146.189.0.0-16-udr"
                addressPrefix    = "146.189.0.0/16"
                nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
                nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.200"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what is the question here.

Comment: @MarkoE  In simple term I don't want to put value of route table all the time in tfvars file.
because same route table value i am giving to all the subnets.
So can we pass the route table value somewhere else?
variables/locals etc.

app-1-subnet = {
addressPrefix                     = "10.229.198.0/24" #required
**route_table =umms-security-rt**

Comment: And why is using tfvars file the wrong approach here?

Comment: @MarkoE i have created varibles files as 
network as map of object under that subnet is map of object and under subnet route table is map of object and routes is list of object.

and i have added route table as optional
so that i dont have to add route table in all subnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we put route table value somewhere else eg other tfvars file or varibles/local and then just in the tfvars file. we can call route table route_table

Yes, you can store the value of the route table in variables instead of directly in the `tfvars` file. This allows you to define the route table value in variables and reference it in `tfvars` file.

Here is the updated **Terraform** code.

Main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "vnetrg" {
  name     = "VNET-RG"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "security-vnet" {
  name                = "security-vnet"
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-without-rt" {
  name                 = "subnet-without-rt"
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefixes[0]]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.security-vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-with-rt" {
  name                 = "subnet-with-rt"
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefixes[1]]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.security-vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "subnet-with-rt-association" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet-with-rt.id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.security-rt.id
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "security-rt" {
  name                = "security-rt"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vnetrg.name

  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = var.route_table["security-rt"].routes
    content {
      name             = route.value.name
      address_prefix   = route.value.addressPrefix
      next_hop_type    = route.value.nextHopType
      next_hop_in_ip_address = route.value.nextHopIpAddress
    }
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "address_space" {
  description = "Address space for the virtual network"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "subnet_prefixes" {
  description = "Prefixes for the subnets"
  type        = list(string)
}
variable "route_table" {
  description = "Route table configuration"
  type        = map(object({
    disableBgpRoutePropagation = bool
    routes = list(object({
      name             = string
      addressPrefix    = string
      nextHopType      = string
      nextHopIpAddress = string
    }))
  }))
  default     = {
    security-rt = {
      disableBgpRoutePropagation = false
      routes = [
        {
          name             = "default-udr"
          addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0"
          nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
          nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.100"
        },
        {
          name             = "network-146.189.0.0-16-udr"
          addressPrefix    = "146.189.0.0/16"
          nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
          nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.200"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
address_space = ["10.229.192.0/20"]

subnet_prefixes = ["10.229.192.0/24", "10.229.198.0/24"]

route_table = {
  "security-rt" = {
    disableBgpRoutePropagation = false
    routes = [
      {
        name             = "default-udr"
        addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0"
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
        nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.100"
      },
      {
        name             = "network-146.189.0.0-16-udr"
        addressPrefix    = "146.189.0.0/16"
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance"
        nextHopIpAddress = "10.231.10.200"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The`route_table` variable is defined in `variables.tf` block, and its value is referenced in the `tfvars` file using `var.route_table["security-rt"]`.

**Terraform Apply**

[image]

Once the ran above **Terraform** code, the resources are   created successfully as below.

[image]

Reference:  [azurestack_virtual_network](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurestack/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network)